# Exporting a string into a specific column in Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

All I want to learn is how to make the ninth column contain Z (the link to the corresponding download file)
I do not get any errors, but it does not execute what I want it to execute.
Any help is really appreciated.

```
import csv; import glob; import os
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
path = 'C:\\Users\\bruno.rojas\\Desktop\\Python_Data\\Test'; extension = 
'csv'; os.chdir(path)


file_name = 'TESTEXCEL'
# Creates empty lists that will hold their corresponding values
links = []
def WebGrab(url, filename):
    req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
    text_file = open(filename+'.csv', "wb")
    text_file.write(webpage)
    text_file.close()
    return text_file
with 
open('C:\\Users\\bruno.rojas\\Desktop\\Python_Data\\test\\'+file_name+'.csv') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
writer = csv.writer(f)
for row in reader:
    links.append("http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+row[0]+"&a="+row[3]+"&b="+row[4]+"&c="+row[2]+"&d="+row[7]+"&e="+row[8]+"&f="+row[6]+"&g=d&ignore=.csv")
    for z in links:
        WebGrab(z, row[0])
        for row in reader:
            row[9] = z
```

Comment: 1. you are reading and writing the same file at the same time (might not be a problem ... haven't tested ... who knows)
2. in the you are trying to use the reader on order to do the writing or something similar ( shouldn't work/ provide the expected result)
3.you have 2 loops with the same iterator (the "row" variable)
try using a "temp file"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_demo.html#ex-demo

Has the below example:

```
##############################################################################
#
# A simple example of some of the features of the XlsxWriter Python module.
#
# Copyright 2013-2016, John McNamara, jmcnamara@cpan.org
#
import xlsxwriter


# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen the first column to make the text clearer.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)

# Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

# Write some simple text.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')

# Text with formatting.
worksheet.write('A2', 'World', bold)

# Write some numbers, with row/column notation.
worksheet.write(2, 0, 123)
worksheet.write(3, 0, 123.456)

# Insert an image.
worksheet.insert_image('B5', 'logo.png')

workbook.close()
```

Comment: The above answer is write only, create only.  If you want to read and then write use my other answer.  I hope that helps!  ∑8•D

Answer (score 0):

I have a better answer...

From this page:

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html

Try these two in order (below)...

Write a workbook

```
>>> from openpyxl import Workbook
>>> from openpyxl.compat import range
>>> from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
>>>
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>>
>>> dest_filename = 'empty_book.xlsx'
>>>
>>> ws1 = wb.active
>>> ws1.title = "range names"
>>>
>>> for row in range(1, 40):
...     ws1.append(range(600))
>>>
>>> ws2 = wb.create_sheet(title="Pi")
>>>
>>> ws2['F5'] = 3.14
>>>
>>> ws3 = wb.create_sheet(title="Data")
>>> for row in range(10, 20):
...     for col in range(27, 54):
...         _ = ws3.cell(column=col, row=row, value="{0}".format(get_column_letter(col)))
>>> print(ws3['AA10'].value)
AA
>>> wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Read an existing workbook

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> wb = load_workbook(filename = 'empty_book.xlsx')
>>> sheet_ranges = wb['range names']
>>> print(sheet_ranges['D18'].value)
3
```

Totally worked for me!

∑8•D